# Making animated GIF only loop once using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, gif

I'm trying to make an introductory animated logo on a website, and I would just like the animation to play through once then trigger a short script that will reveal a "Continue" button. I was hoping there would be a way in the HTML to just tell the GIF to only cycle once, but I cannot find any such attribute or tag. So now I can't find any kind of trigger function after the GIF finished animating, and it's driving me crazy!

I would appreciate any help either solving this issue or being directed to a better animation format to get around all this nonsense.

Comment: Not how Gifs work, sorry. There is no event raised when a gif has "finished", and looping is controlled by the gif itself.

Comment: so... HTML doesn't control GIF loops, GIF's do. So you have several choices, the best being use a setTimeout with javascript or make your own GIF that doesn't loop or both.

Comment: You can use any image and let it rotate with the help of css3 animations

Comment: I was linked to [this site](http://gifshake.com/gifs/4N0CUvDx) once, which seemed to be able to manipulate gifs very well. I'll be checking their code if I can find if it's possible to do that with JavaScript only (so not server-side).

Comment: GIMP can save GIFs with an attribute whether to cycle or to be only played once.

Comment: I was able to eliminate the looping with GIMP! Thanks :D

Answer (score 3):

I've looked through the code on http://gifshake.com, and it looks like that site uses http://gifshake.com/assets/application-0d2f240603d4b373f1d6768aa71baf42.js to convert its gifs to an interactive canvas. In case you're wondering, the code they use is:

```
var sup1 = new SuperGif({ gif: document.getElementById('thegif') } );
sup1.load();
```

where the element with `id="thegif"` is an image with the `src` attribute that contains the url to the gif image. Anyway, I think there's no real easy way to control a gif like that, other than importing those same libraries as they do. For a situation like yours, I don't think that's the most practical solution though. You'd be best off simply editing the gif in an image editor such as GIMP and setting it to play just once, instead of infinitely. You can do that by opening the GIF, then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> (export), and save it as a gif. Then when changing the further options, save it as an animation and uncheck the checkbox that says '*Loop forever*'. I hope that helps.

TL;DR: It's not possible to do this with an overseeable amount of JavaScript alone; you're better off simply editing the gif yourself.

Comment: It is also worth noting that when setting a GIF to loop once, most browsers will obey, but some will loop it twice. That is because you've the value of "loop" to "1". Some browsers take this to mean "play the GIF 1 time" which is what we want. Others take it to mean "loop the GIF 1 time" (or, play the GIF twice).

Comment: @tomysshadow - ha, like when somebody tells me his at some building at floor 1, I never know if that's the ground floor or one above it

Comment: It is weird logic, I know.